# angularjs Route timeouts randomly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I use `$routeprovider` in my angularjs app to load views into my `index.html` file. Usually everything works great, but once in a while I get a `500 server error` and a subsequent timeout error.

I assume the problem is in the `$routeprovider` since I see the html of the index page (header and footer but not the content) and there are no exceptions on the API that could cause any of this.

my app file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'LocalStorageModule', 'ngLoadScript', 'autocomplete', 'chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'toastr']);

app.config(['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 'cfpLoadingBarProvider',
function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    var baseTemplateUrl = "app/Views/"

    $routeProvider
       .when("/home", {
           templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "home.html",
           controller: "homeController"
       })
       .when("/", {
           templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "home.html",
           controller: "homeController"
       })

     .when("/pricing", {
         templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "pricing.html",
         controller: "pricingController"
     })
             .when("/blog", {
                 templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "Blog.html",
                 controller: "blogController"
             })
         .when("/article/:id", {
             templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "Article.html",
             controller: "articleController"
         })
            .when("/contact", {
                templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "contact.html",
                controller: "contactController"
            })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;
}]);
```

All my views are .html files.

Any idea how to solve it?
thanks

Comment: _"I get a 500 server error"_, _"I assume the problem is in the $routeprovider"_ - Can you spot the contradiction?

Comment: the 500 server error i have is while loading the whole route, and not on a specific post/get function.
for example, error 500 on /home request.
i also see the headers/footers but not the content of view in the ng-view tag.
thats why i assume its something with the routeprovider

Comment: **Server** error means just that: An error, that occurred on the server. `$routeprovider` runs on the client. You have a problem with the server. I don't know what you mean by your comment, but loading a route actually **is** a specific `GET` request.

Comment: okay, lets forget about the routeprovider for a second. when the error 500 happens, the debugger does not even reach the app file.
also, no error on the API actually happens since i log every exception on all controller actions.

Comment: If by controller action you mean the server side, then you assume that the request reaches the controller. Have you checked that? Are you 100% sure that **every** exception get logged? What we can be 100% sure of is that there's a problem on the server. 500 means "Something went wrong. That shouldn't have happened". And since you mentioned a timeout there may be a conflict or another problem concerning (a) resource(s).

Comment: 100% the code doesn't reach the server side and 100% no exception happens.
what kind of a problem could be concerning (a) resource(s)?

Comment: When the client receives an http status code then the request has reached the server. Where else should the response come from? It may not have reached the application running there, though. A resource problem could be blocking threads, limited memory, failing disks, internal network problems etc. If it's your server, then check it. If not, and you don't have full access, then contact your provider.